# Jhipster : issue with accents of $scope variables

Tags: angularjs, diacritics, jhipster

My controller and html files are encoded in UTF-8. 
If in my controller I set a scope variable with an accent, it is not well displayed in the view. 
Example :

> $scope.test = 'Impôts'

in my controller turns to

> impÃ´ts

in the view.

Any idea of where it can come from?

Comment: Make sure you have `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in head section of the HTML file.

Comment: the charset is good in my head section